# Can't call the outOfBound function

Tags: c++

I can't seem to call this no matter how I tried. It says Error: use of undeclared identifier "outOfBound". How do I call the outOfBound function to my hh function properly? Thanks

```
void hh(int var1, int var2, int var3, char char_a, char char_b, char array[10][10])
{
    if(outOfBound(var1, var2, var3))
    {
        cout << "Error: image access out of bounds (0, 0)";
        exit(0);
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < var3; i++)
    {
        array[var1 - 1][var2 - 1 + i] = char_b;
    }
}

bool outOfBound(int var1, int var2, int var3)
{
    if(var1 < 1 || var1 > 10 || var2 < 1 || var2 > 10 || var3 < 1 || var3 > 10)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt at calling this function, and provide the exact compiler message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared the function after trying to use it, it has to be before:

```
bool outOfBound(int var1, int var2, int var3);

void hh(int var1, int var2, int var3, char char_a, char char_b, char array[10][10])
{
    if(outOfBound(var1, var2, var3))
    {
        cout << "Error: image access out of bounds (0, 0)";
        exit(0);
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < var3; i++)
    {
        array[var1 - 1][var2 - 1 + i] = char_b;
    }
}

bool outOfBound(int var1, int var2, int var3)
{
    if(var1 < 1 || var1 > 10 || var2 < 1 || var2 > 10 || var3 < 1 || var3 > 10)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also the `if(...) { return true; } else { return false; }` "pattern" can simply be written as `return ...;`

Comment: I'd even suggest putting the whole definition of `outOfBound` above `hh` to not have to forward declare it.

Comment: and i would also pull the `cout` and `exit` inside the function (perhaps optionally offering other exit strategies)